# Does Python not follow IEEE-754 in case of division by zero?

Tags: python, floating-point, runtime-error, ieee-754, divide-by-zero

Here's a toy example in case of which Python exhibits behaviour that surprised me:

```
def harmonic_mean(x, y):
    return 2/(1/x+1/y)

print(harmonic_mean(0.0, 1.0))
```

In IEEE-754 division by `0.0` shouldn't halt execution but rather it should just produce `inf` (or `-inf` or `NaN`). Because of that, the above code should work even if one of the arguments is `0.0`. However, it seems to instead halt and print `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero`. Does that mean that Python doesn't follow IEEE-754 standard even on a platform that supports it? What's the motivation for making dividing by `0.0` cause a runtime error instead of producing a result that the standard prescribes? Do I have a way around that other than explicitly checking for zeros? I know that in this particular example I could instead e.g. use the following:

```
def harmonic_mean(x, y):
    return 2*x*y/(x+y)
```

However, I would like to know what I can do more generally.

EDIT: I'll add that one reason I was surprised was that I had already seen NumPy behave mostly as I would have expected in a case of divide by zero. As an example, consider something like `np.array([-1.0, 0.0, 1.0])/0.0`. The divide by zero causes a warning that reads `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide` to be printed in the command line but the result is still `[-inf  nan  inf]` as I would've expected.

Comment: It is good practice to avoid dividing by zero whenever it is possible to do so. I'm inclined to think that languages like Python that hard fault division by zero and halt are a bit less likely to be hiding bugs.  Most times that people divide by zero it signifies a fault in their algorithm so I am inclined to the view that the IEEE 754 standard although convenient is misguided in allowing execution to continue with an inf result. BTW your second method can still fail if x == -y or 2*x*y > max_real

Comment: @MartinBrown I have to disagree. I think the way IEEE-754 handles division by zero and other similar cases is both handy and elegant. I think it's a pity that Python does things differently. Then, as to your last point. I don't think the `x==-y` case matters that much. Usually, harmonic mean isn't considered for negative numbers and even if you did that, in that kind of case the result wouldn't be a finite number. However, the case of `2*x*y>max_real` is more salient and probably a decent example of the downsides of the current choice in Python.

Comment: Not only is `harmonic_mean(x, y)` supposed to be undefined for non-positive `x` and `y`, it is supposed to be bounded from above by `2 * min(x, y)`. Having `harmonic_mean(0, 1)` return infinity would violate that.

Comment: Having `1/0` return `inf` was, I always understood, a way to indicate an exception in languages without such support without necessarily raising a hardware exception. It's still up to the code to decide if a result of `inf` for a particular operation means it's OK to continue.

Comment: @chepner But `harmonic_mean(0.0, 1.0)` is supposed to return `0.0`, not an infinity, so there would be no such violation. With IEEE-754 arithmetic `harmonic_mean(0.0, 1.0)` returns `0.0` as expected.

Comment: For reference, the cpython implementation is in the `float_div` function in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/floatobject.c. Zero division is expressly checked and errored.

Comment: There is one thing I find a bit inconsistent. Otherwise, both way would be ok by me. I am fine with using IEEE-754 way, even tho it is not magic, and requires for example to handle carefuly the signs of 0 and ∞. In your case for example, it requires whoever calls the function to be aware that 0 is the positive 0. But I am also fine with a language saying "we using underlying IEEE-754 internally, but in our language, there is no such thing as 1/0". But the thing I find a bit inconsistent is `1/(1.0e10000)` is `inf` and `1/(1/(1.0e1000))` is an error.

Comment: @QuantumWiz I skipped a step and missed that the infinities themselves become denominators, resulting in 0 in IEEE-754. But the point remains that the harmonic mean of 0 and 1 is *not* supposed to be 0, either; it's *undefined*.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean (which explicitly requires positive numbers) and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicMean.html (which is vague, but refers to power means which, though defined for non-negative numbers in general, appears to be require positive numbers for the special case of the harmonic mean.)

Comment: Re “In IEEE-754 division by `0.0` shouldn't halt execution…”: IEEE 754 does not specify that. When a finite non-zero number is divided by zero, the “division by zero” exception is signaled. (An IEEE-754 exception means something abnormal has happened; it does not mean a change of control necessarily happens like a C++ exception.) What happens then depends on whether default exception handling or alternate exception handling is set. With default exception handling, an infinity is provided and the division-by-zero flag is raised…

Comment: … For alternate exception handling, a variety of things can happen, intended to be largely under program control. Generating a program trap is a potential behavior. The standard says language standards “should” arrange for language implementations to give the user means to control alternate exception handling in various ways (IEEE 754-2019 8.1). Python does not have a standard or a formal specification, so it is unclear what that means for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the IEEE 754-2019 standard:

> **exception:** An event that occurs when an operation on some particular operands has no outcome suitable for every reasonable application. That operation might signal an exception by invoking default exception handling or alternate exception handling. Exception handling might signal further exceptions. Recognize that event, exception, and signal are defined in diverse ways in different programming environments.

In other words, while continuing execution as normal with an `Inf` or `NaN` result would be a compliant response to attempted division by zero, so would a non-local return, as is the case with Python.

The motivation for this is the assumption that a division of this sort is probably accidental, and that (all things considered) it would be better to immediately signal an error than to allow the result to cause more subtle errors later on. If this doesn't fit your needs, you can use `numpy` for different semantics.

From [The Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/):

> Errors should never pass silently.
> Unless explicitly silenced.

To that point, '754 also recommends that implementations allow the user to modify the semantics of exception handling, such as to pass without error, log the error elsewhere, and/or substitute some arbitrary result. But this is not a requirement of the '754 standard: It uses the word "should" which it defines elsewhere as indicating that it is "particularly suitable" or "preferred but not necessarily required".

Comment: Actually, one reason I was surprised by the behaviour is that I had seen divide by zero behave mostly as I expected in NumPy. I think I'll add a mention of that to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The newer `decimal` module can be configured to conform with the later base-independent generalizations of 754, but Python `float` semantics cannot be.

```py
Python 3.12.2 (tags/v3.12.2:6abddd9, ...
...
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(1) / 0 # by defaalt, this also raises
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
decimal.DivisionByZero: [<class 'decimal.DivisionByZero'>]
>>> decimal.getcontext().traps[decimal.DivisionByZero] = False
>>> decimal.Decimal(1) / 0 # but, as above, can be turned off
Decimal('Infinity')
```

Python predates the introduction of 754, and backward compatibility in this area has always been considered more important. Core Python doesn't claim to conform to any floating-point standard (although the `decimal` module does).

In much earlier days, some people introduced layers of cruft to try to make this optional, but, at the time, there was such massive variation among the many C environments in use (CPython is coded in C, and inherits a lot from platform C semantics) that people gave up.

It would probably be easier to do today, but it seems nobody cares enough to volunteer the effort.

Comment: I don't think Python predates IEEE-754 which was first published in 1985. Also, Python 3 isn't backward compatible with earlier versions in any case, right?

Comment: For "predates", read "before widely implemented by C compilers". Python wasn't interested in running only in Apple's SANE environment ;-)

Comment: @QuantumWiz, yes, backward-incompatible changes have been made. It's always a major undertaking, and there has to a truly compelling case for it to even get serious consideration.

Answer (score 2):

This is discussed for example [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/75116) or [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/94621).

According to those discussions, Python does follow IEEE-754 by signalling overflows or singularities by raising an exception.

Comment: Is there a reference for IEEE-754 that explicitly states an exception as an acceptable outcome?

Comment: As far as I understand those sections are referenced in the second link I included and the standard allows for "signalling" which the Python devs interpret is fulfilled by an exception. The best I could find is this comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/94621#issuecomment-1177160889

Comment: The handling of exceptions like `ZeroDivisionError` is part of Python's standard library and its runtime env, rather than a reflection of following  or non-adherence to IEEE-754.

Comment: No claim is made to adhere to the IEEE-754 specification, only that behavior not described by Python itself is delegated to the underlying platform, which may or may not by IEEE-754-compliant. (The fact that the may-not contingent is nearly non-existent is beside the point.)

Comment: I think in the IEEE-754 text "exception" means a different thing than what it means in most programming languages. I think it just means raising some flags but allowing the execution to continue even if you don't check them. The equivalent of what "exception" means in most programming languages, i.e. you have to handle it or execution stops, is called "trap" instead.

Comment: @QuantumWiz: Yes, it means something different from exceptions in programming languages that change program control. It does not mean raising flags. It means an ordinary mathematical result is not possible, i.e., something exceptional has occurred. Then what happens may vary, depending on program or language choices. Default exception handling is to supply a default result and raise a corresponding flag. Alternate exception handling has various choices, of which generating a program trap is a common one.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Re “Is there a reference for IEEE-754 that explicitly states an exception as an acceptable outcome?”: Alternate exception handling (versus default supplying a default result and raising a flag) is specified in IEEE 754-2019 clause 8.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I feel that the wording "an ordinary mathematical result is not possible" is a bit misleading since roundoff error is an exception too.

Comment: @QuantumWiz: What do you mean? The inexact exception of IEEE-754 applies here too. In `1./3.`, the ordinary-math result of ⅓ is not a possible result because it is not representable, so there is an inexact exception. That is not misleading; the statement that the ordinary-math result is not possible is correct, and the floating-point implementation correctly indicates the exception. In most software, trapping for that exception is left off, and the default result is produced, which is the rounded value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OK, I misunderstood you. I thought you would have classified that as an ordinary result.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing a non-zero number by zero should yield infinity (`inf` or `-inf`, depending on the sign), and `0.0 / 0.0` should produce `NaN` (Not a Number).

However, Python raises a `ZeroDivisionError` exception in certain cases to alert the programmer to a potential problem rather than silently returning `inf`, `-inf`, or `NaN`.

This is a **design choice** and it does not indicate non-compliance with IEE-754, but rather a preference.

In practice, Python Does follow IEEE-754 when it comes to the actual representation and behavior of floating-point numbers, including the handling of special cases like `infinity` and `NaN`.

```py
positive_infinity = float('inf')
negative_infinity = float('-inf')

print(positive_infinity)  # Output: inf
print(negative_infinity)  # Output: -inf
print(0.0 / 0.0)  # Output: nan

print(positive_infinity + 1)  # Output: inf
print(positive_infinity * -1)  # Output: -inf

print(positive_infinity > 1000000)  # Output: True
print(negative_infinity < -1000000)  # Output: True

print(positive_infinity - positive_infinity)  # Output: nan
print(0.0 * positive_infinity)  # Output: nan
```